# Regular Expression to validate Rate of Interest Format Swift3

Tags: swift3

I have been trying to work on Regular Expressions for one of my TextField to only allow digits in Rate of Interest format.

I want the field to allow input of max 2 digits before "." character and max 2 digits after.

Valid Formats:

> 1, 10, 1.2, 11.4, 15.24

And Max length of the field to be 5 characters

I tried a few but nothing worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
let string = "10.55"

if let match = string.range(of: "^\\d{1,2}(\\.\\d{1,2})?$", options: .regularExpression) {
    print("Match")
}
```

Or you can use guard too

```
guard let match = string.range(of: "^\\d{1,2}(\\.\\d{1,2})?$", options: .regularExpression) else {
    return
}
```

Comment: Hello @Parth Adroja ..Thanks for the response but i an getting error "invalid escape sequence in literal"

Comment: @Rachna Most Welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that you want to match with the whole field, I think this may work out:

```
^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Comment: Hello @thanhlvt ..Thanks for the response but i an getting error "invalid escape sequence in literal"

Comment: I used common Regex literal string, but in swift, you should use double slash like this: ^\\d{1,2}(\\.\\d{1,2})?$